# Asp.net MVC5 Deployment to 3rd Party Server, could not find my database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

I have successfully deploy my application with left click to project folder and publish. I have also fill my server and SQL server information which is in Settings tab. Everything is OK but when i look at my server with sql server management tools i could not see my DB file but i can CRUD also...

Where is my DB created ?

Here is my config file connection infor after deployment, it seems it is changed to my live DB which is correct.

```
<configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=94.***.***.***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*******" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection_DatabasePublish" connectionString="Data Source= ***********;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=******" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Is it still pointing to your dev DB?

Comment: should i need to change config file since i am using deployment tool ?

Comment: I would check it. I have never used the deployment tool myself. On the server you have deployed too, just check the web.config and check where the connection string is pointing too!

Comment: What is your way to deploy your mvc codefirst applications? Could you please explain me .. I am also going to check my config file when i have my notebook in 1 hour.

Comment: I have included my connection string to my question, It seems it changed.

Comment: I see you have two connectiom strings listed DefaultConnection_DatabasePublish and DefaultConnection make sure your code is referencing the correct connection string. Also make sure the database is created on your server. I also do not see an initial catalog in your connection string.

Comment: Actually, i did not change any connection string. Before deployment there is only DefaultConnection  which map to LocalDb, after deployment, ASP.net generate these connection strings.. Both connection strings are referencing my development server.

Comment: Have you checked your config transformations? (click the plus next to web.config) One of my projects I deploy straight from VS using one click publish and I have config transformations for each environment. Sounds like you have another connection string in a transform file